# Magento - Currency - 404 Not Found - The requested URL /directory/currency/switch/currency/USD/ was not found on this server

Tags: magento, url, http-status-code-404, currency

Recently I bought theme and now I have troubles with currencies.

When I switch the currency I got message like that:

```
The requested URL /directory/currency/switch/currency/USD/uenc/aHR0cDovL3ZvdmFuLm5pY2t3bGtlci5jb20v/ was not found on this server.
```

But if I go back I'll see that currency changed.

How to prevent this "error" ?

Comment: I only can see that it works.

Comment: If you change the currency from "RUB" to "USD" you'll see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I was needed to remove index.php from url in magento.

I did that:

1) System >> Configuration >> Web >> Search Engines Optimization >> Use Web Server Rewrites : YES

2) System >> Configuration >> Web >> Secure >> Use secure URL Frontend: YES

3) Then created the .htaccess file under my magento installed folder with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for trying help me.